# Como verificar se existir agendamento em um intervalo de horários?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Preciso criar uma agenda onde aloco um prestador de serviços para trabalhar para um cliente.

> Por ex: O PrestadorDeServicos João vai prestar serviços para o cliente
>   *condomínio vale do sol* no dia *15 de março de 2016 de 10:00 às 12:00*.

João não pode ser cadastrado no mesmo dia/horário pra outro cliente.

Tendo a tabela *PrestadorDeServicos com nome e  PK cod_prestador*, *Cliente com razaoSocial e  PK cod_cliente* e *Agendamento com  DateTime Inicio , DateTime Fim, FK_prestador, FK_Cliente e PK cod_agendamento*.

Como faço para garantir que um prestador de serviços nunca seja alocado no mesmo momento em clientes distintos?

Comment: Usando trigger : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355921/sql-server-2008-help-writing-simple-insert-trigger, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502802/trigger-to-prevent-insertion-for-duplicate-data-of-two-columns

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert se alguém tentar cadastrar joão de 11:00 às 13:00 no dia 15 de março de 2016, como sei que esse horário colide com o agendamento de 10:00 e 12:00 de 15 de março de 2016?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012099/query-to-check-overlapping-ranges-in-sql-server, no postgres serial **overlaps** `(TIMESTAMP '2016-03-10 10:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2016-03-10 12:00:00') OVERLAPS (TIMESTAMP '2016-03-10 11:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2016-03-10 13:00:00')`

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert Excelente, brigadão !!

Comment: Útil esta "overlaps" !!

Answer (score -1):

Você pode criar uma verificação antes de fazer o `Insert`, checando se a sua tabela já contém a informação que você esta passando.

```
declare @table table
(
  cod_prestador int,
  DateTimeInicio DateTime , 
  DateTimeFim DateTime
)

declare @DateTimeInicio datetime = '15-03-2016 12:00:00', @DateTimeFim DateTime = '15-03-2016 14:00:00'

insert into @table values 
(1,'15-03-2016 10:00:00', '15-03-2016 12:00:00')

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @table 
            WHERE @DateTimeFim <= DateTimeFim 
            AND @DateTimeInicio >= DateTimeInicio)

  print 'Aqui existi, não faça o insert ou retorne o erro.'
ELSE
   print 'Aqui você pode inserir'
```